# changepoint detection and its analysis

Tags: time-series, data-mining, change-point, sequential-analysis, structural-change

I applied changepoint detection provided by `ecp` package against a given time series. The time series plot marked with identified change points is shown as follows. My question is that, given such a plot, how can I explain to the audience why these are change points. [image] Just based on the observing the plot, it seems to me that it is not very clear why these should be change points.

Comment: Post your data.

Comment: I would agree that this is an example of "overcalling" probably due to some ill-advised non-parametric method/approach.Sometimes free software has a price.

Comment: @Tom, I may not be able to share the data. Sorry about that. If I am a user, when given this kind of result. The first question may be why I cannot treat every turning point as the change point. Based on the plot, all of the identified change points happen to be the turning point as well. Why some are chosen, and others are not.

Comment: Scale it and becomes deidentified.